# transpose of a list of lists

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to make a recursive function to get the transpose of a list of lists, `n x p` to `p x n`. But i'm unable to do so. I've been able to make a function to transpose a `3 x n` list of lists to an `n x 3` one:

```
let rec drop1 list=
    [(match (List.nth list 0) with [] -> [] | a::b -> b);
     (match (List.nth list 1) with [] -> [] | a::b -> b);
     (match (List.nth list 2) with [] -> [] | a::b -> b);]

let rec transpose list=
    if List.length (List.nth list 0) == 0 then []
    else [(match (List.nth list 0) with [] -> 0 | a::b -> a);
          (match (List.nth list 1) with [] -> 0 | a::b -> a);
          (match (List.nth list 2) with [] -> 0 | a::b -> a)]
         :: transpose (drop1 list)
```

But I'm not able to generalize it. I'm surely thinking in the wrong direction. Is this generalizable? Is there a better solution? Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
let rec transpose list = match list with
| []             -> []
| []   :: xss    -> transpose xss
| (x::xs) :: xss ->
    (x :: List.map List.hd xss) :: transpose (xs :: List.map List.tl xss)
```

Taking advantage of syntax changes since answer first posted:

```
let rec transpose list = match list with
| []             -> []
| []      :: xss -> transpose xss
| (x::xs) :: xss ->
    List.(
      (x :: map hd xss) :: transpose (xs :: map tl xss)
    )
```

Comment: +1, Wow! I was not aware of List.map function. The manual says its not tail-recursive. What effect can that have if I use this in a bigger code?

Comment: @lalli: For very large lists it can cause a stack overflow. In that case, you should use `List.rev_map` instead and then go through the lists at the end and reverse them. Note however that my definition of `transpose` is also not tail recursive (neither is yours).

Comment: You should not worry about tail-recursivity at first; try to have a simple and clear implementation.

Using a "transpose" function on ('a list list) with very big lists is probably a very bad idea anyway. If you have lots of data, an other data structure (eg. a matrix indexed by (int * int), which has a constant-time `transpose` function) is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Note that this fails with inputs such as `[[0]; []]`

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had to solve this as part of an exercise I was doing, and I came across @sepp2k's solution, but I couldn't understand how it worked, so I tried to arrive at it by myself.

This is essentially the same algorithm, but a little bit more terse, as it does not destructure the list of lists. I thought I would post it here in case anyone else is searching, and might find this way of expressing it useful:

```
let rec transpose = function
   | [] 
   | [] :: _ -> []
   | rows    -> 
       List.map List.hd rows :: transpose (List.map List.tl rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the matrix is rectangular (otherwise `Invalid_argument "map2"` will be raised):

```
let transpose m =
  if m = [] then [] else
  List.(fold_right (map2 cons) m @@ map (fun _ -> []) (hd m))
```

Note that `map (fun _ -> []) (hd m)` just creates a list of empty lists, of length equal to the number of columns in `m`.

So a clearer representation of this code would be:

```
let transpose m =
  if m = [] then [] else
  let open List in
  let empty_rows = map (fun _ -> []) (hd m) in
  fold_right (map2 cons) m empty_rows
```