# How do I use List.map to apply a function on a int list list?

Tags: list, dictionary, ocaml

Suppose I have a `(int list list) x = [[1;1;1]; [2;2;2]; [3;4;5]]` and a function f. The result should be `[f [1;1;1]; f [2;2;2]; f[3;4;5]].` The built in List.map works only for int list but not for int list list.The i-th entry in this new column is computed by the function f which is taking as input the i-th element from each column in the spreadsheet and forms a new element.

`let newList x f = List.map f x` (* this is the only map function that I know *)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `List.map f` as a function, which works on one dimensional lists, and then `map` that function on the two-dimensional list as follows:

```
let x = [[1;1;1]; [2;2;2]; [3;4;5]];; 
let f x = x + 1;; 
List.map (List.map f) x;;
```

output:

```
- : int list list = [[2; 2; 2]; [3; 3; 3]; [4; 5; 6]]
```

> my function will take as input two arguments, an int list list and a
>   function f. It will output a new int list. Input = m = [[x1;x2;x3] ;
>   [y1;y2;y3] ; [z1;z2;z3]] and function f Output = [f [x1;y1;z1] ; f
>   [x2;y2;z2] ; f [x3;y3;z3]]

It seems that you wanted to transpose (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3989823/4196578) your 2-D array and then map `f`. In that case, you can do:

```
let rec transpose list = match list with
| []             -> []
| []   :: xss    -> transpose xss
| (x::xs) :: xss ->
    (x :: List.map List.hd xss) :: transpose (xs :: List.map List.tl xss);;

let myfunc m f = List.map f (transpose m);;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. How can I make a new column where i-th element of the new column will be the result when f is called on all the i-th elements of all the columns in the initial int list list. eg. for the 3rd element of the new column, we call function f on [1;2;5]. So the complete result of the new column would be [f [1;2;3]; f [1;2;4]; f[1;2;5]].

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly. What is the exact definition of `f`? In your original question f is `: int -> int`, now is `f` a different type?

Comment: Suppose I am given an int list list m = [[x1;x2;x3] ; [y1;y2;y3] ; [z1;z2;z3]]. How can I make a new int list list m' = [[x1;y1;z1] ; [x2;y2;z2] ; [x3;y3;z3]] and then apply a function f using List.map to get result = [f [x1;y1;z1] ; f [x2;y2;z2] ; f [x3;y3;z3]] ?

Comment: so what is the input type and what's the output type of `f`?

Comment: If `f2` takes a `int list` as input, you can simply do: `List.map f2 x;;`

Comment: my function will take as input two arguments, an int list list and a function f. It will output a new int list.
Input  =  m = [[x1;x2;x3] ; [y1;y2;y3] ; [z1;z2;z3]] and function f
Output = [f [x1;y1;z1] ; f [x2;y2;z2] ; f [x3;y3;z3]]