# Tranpose a list list in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec transpose list = match list with
| []             -> []
| []   :: xss    -> transpose xss
| (x::xs) :: xss ->
    (x :: List.map List.hd xss) :: transpose (xs :: List.map List.tl xss)
```

I found this code on this website and it transposes a list list or in my case a matrix from n × m to m × n.The only problem is I have no idea how it works. Can anyone please explain it step by step, line by line.

Comment: This is not what this site is for, but you can get plenty of learning resources from https://ocaml.org/learn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide the link to the code as well, for context, or look on that question for an explanation.

Either way, I suspect other new OCaml programmers will come to this question looking for an answer.

-- After a quick Google search I believe this was the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989776/transpose-of-a-list-of-lists) you found the code from.

`let rec transpose list = match list with`

- Create a function called transpose, make it recursive (rec) as we will make the function call itself. It will take an input parameter called `list`, where the type is determined by OCaml's type-system later.
- Match the input parameter `list` with the following cases. That is, when the function finds a pattern matching those cases, it will execute that particular line of code. If code written does not cover all cases, OCaml will notify that not all cases are exhaustive and will cause a `match_failure` if it encounters cases that it doesn't cover.

First case:

`| []             -> []`

- If we hit an empty list, return an empty list. This will end the recursion as the empty list is appended to the final result and returned. The empty list is a base case, where we meet a list with nothing inside, or it has recursed till there is nothing left. (the transpose of an empty list is ... and empty list)

`| []   :: xss    -> transpose xss`

- This is the case where there are still items in the list. Since it is a list of list, each element in the list we pass in is another list. i.e, `[[1;2];[3;4]]`, so this function handles the case where we have `[[];[1;2];[5;6]]`, it will skip the empty inner list, and then call transpose on the other `[[1;2];[5;6]]`, since we don't need to transpose an empty list. Note that `xss` is the rest of the list (hence list of list), not just the next element only (which is just a list).

`| (x::xs) :: xss ->
    (x :: List.map List.hd xss) :: transpose (xs :: List.map List.tl xss)`

- This is the first case that will be matched when we pass in any regular list of list of length > 1, OCaml is able to match and also "unwrap" each element by breaking it down to fit the pattern, so we can immediately compute those elements without using nested `match` statements. In this case, we split the list of list into the `(x::xs)` list (first element) and the remaining list of list, `xss`. We could have also done it as `x::xss` but x will be a list that we need to break down into individual elements again. 
  For example, in `[[1;2];[3;4]]`, (x::xs) will be [1;2] and `xss` will be [[3;4]]
- `(x :: List.map List.hd xss)` will take the first element in the first list, in the given example, x will be 1. And apply that value to the `List.hd` of every item in `xss` list, (`List.Map` applies a function to every value in the list).
- This is where it seems a little complicated. How you can look at it is: When you call `List.hd [1;2;3]` it will return 1 since it's the head. So when we do `3 :: List.map List.hd [[1;2]]` it will return `int list = [3; 1]`. and it we did `3 :: List.map List.hd [[1;2];[4;5]]` we get `[3;1;4]` as we are getting the head of every list inside the larger list, and appending 3 at the front of the resulting list.
- If you did `List.map List.tl [[1;2];[4;5]]` instead your return type would be [2;5] since List.map applies the List.tl function to every list. You can use `List.map` to apply say a multiplication function (or anything complicated) to each item in the list in a quick and easy way.

The remaining `transpose (xs :: List.map List.tl xss)` just calls transpose to the remaining items in the list, which is the tail values of `xss` (all lists), appended with elements in xs. Try this out on paper if you feel you need a more concrete grasp on it.