# Extracting elements from 2d list

Tags: arrays, list, pattern-matching, ocaml

I have the following 2d list

```
[ [a1 ; a2 ; a3 ; a4] ;
  [b1 ; b2 ; b3 ; b4] ;
  [c1 ; c2 ; c3 ; c4] ]
```

and I have an input function F.
I have the following problem : Given a 2d list m and a function f, compute the i-th value in
   the result column c by using the i-th value from each column in m.

```
[ f [a1; b1; c1]; f [a2; b2; c2]; f [a3; b3; c3]; f [a4; b4; c4]; f [a5; b5; c5] ]
```

How can I create a list of the first elements of each sublist? I was thinking of using the List.map function but I am not sure what function to pass to it so I can get those results.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code.

Comment: @Akrion, haven't tried anything as I am not sure how to access specific elements of the sublists in OCaml

Comment: Do you know how to get an element out of just one list?

Comment: @glennsl yep I can pattern match on the list with hd::tl

Comment: Ok, good, and so since patterns can be nested you should be able to replace `hd` with another list pattern to get the elements of the sublist.

Comment: Okay, I can access the a1 (first element of first sublist), how can I access simulatiously a1, a2 and a3 so I can pass [a1; a2; a3] to the function f ?

Comment: You can also use a fixed-size list pattern: `[a1; a2; a3]` which will match a list with exactly 3 elements and bind each element to `a1`, `a2` and `a3` respectively. You can use this pattern both on the inner lists and the outer list and mix it with the cons (`hd::tl`) pattern.

Comment: Problem is that I do not know how big the main list is nor the sublists. They might not be size 3 always

Comment: That's not what your question says.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand the question.

But, as I can see from your example, I would transpose your list of lists (see [transpose of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989776/transpose-of-a-list-of-lists))

example:

```
let rec transpose list = 
  match list with
  | []           -> []
  | []::xss      -> transpose xss
  | (x::xs)::xss ->
    (x :: List.map List.hd xss) :: transpose (xs :: List.map List.tl xss);;

//An example of int list list
let m=[ [11 ; 12 ; 13 ; 14] ;
        [21 ; 22 ; 23 ; 24] ;
        [31 ; 32 ; 33 ; 34] ];;

//An example of int list-> int function
let f list = List.fold_right (+) list 0;;

List.map f (transpose m);;
```

This gives:

```
[f [11;21;31]; f [12;22;32]; f [13;23;33]; f [14;24;34]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this :

```
open List;;

let map2d f l =
  let rec aux acc l =
    try (
      let l'=map hd l and
          l =map tl l in
      aux (f l'::acc) l
    ) with _ -> rev acc
  in
  if l=[] then [] else aux [] l
;;
```

Test

```
let f = fold_left (+) 0;;
let id x = x;;

let m=[ [11 ; 12 ; 13 ; 14] ;
        [21 ; 22 ; 23 ; 24] ;
        [31 ; 32 ; 33 ; 34] ];; 

# map2d id m;;
- : int list list = [[11; 21; 31]; [12; 22; 32]; [13; 23; 33]; [14; 24; 34]]

# map2d f m;;
- : int list = [63; 66; 69; 72]

# map2d id [[11;21];[12];[13]];;
- : int list list = [[11; 12; 13]]

# map2d id [[];[]];;
- : 'a list list = []
# map2d f [[];[]];;
- : int list = []
```